# Is it possible to deploy asp.net mvc project on IIS server without installing of mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

Is it possible to deploy asp.net mvc project on IIS server without installing of mvc?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? No is the answer I believe, but I'm curious as to the why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. This is possible. This blog post...

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/03/bin-deploy-aspnetmvc.aspx

... is a little old but gives you some of the details. ASP.NET MVC is designed to be xcopy deployable.

Note: You'll need IIS7. Lesser versions of IIS require additional script mappings.

Answer (score 4):

You can, just click the "copy to local" property on the referenced MVC .dll's

**UPDATE:** In your project in Visual Studio, find "References" in the solution explorer. Find System.Web.MVC, right-click on it and select properties. Set "Copy Local" and "Specific Version" to true.

This means that the MVC .dll files will be copied to your project, and deployed along with it. The specific version property means that this version of the .dll will be used, regardless of wether or not a different one exists on the server.

(Note that you may have to do this for other referenced .dll's as well. System.Web.Routing, for instance).